# How to change the marker image on click of the symbol in ARCGIS API JS?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I tried this approach but its highlighting the symbol. How can i change marker image on click of the symbol.

My code:

```
let centroidRenderer = {
    type: "simple", 
    symbol: {
        type: "picture-marker", 
        // url: "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/582/855/original/vector-location-pin-icon.jpg",
        url: "images/Location-map.png",
        width: "26",
        height: "26"
    }
};

let locationpin = new FeatureLayer({

    url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Centroids/FeatureServer/0",
  
    renderer: centroidRenderer
});
//   var privateSchoolsPoly = new FeatureLayer({
//     url:
//       "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/PrivateSchoolEnrollmentNoRendering/FeatureServer/0",
//     outFields: ["*"],
//     opacity: 0.8,
//     renderer: renderer,

//   });

let symbol;

view.when(async () => {
const layerView = await view.whenLayerView(locationpin);
view.on('click', async (e) => {
    const {results} = await view.hitTest(e);
    try {
        const { graphic } = results.find(x => x.graphic.attributes.OBJECTID);
        if(symbol.url=="images/Location-map.png"){
            (symbol.url==" https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/582/855/original/vector-location-pin-icon.jpg")
        }
        else{
            symbol.url==" images/Location-map.png"
        }
        // fWidget.graphic = graphic;
        symbol = layerView.highlight(graphic);
    } catch(err) {}
});
});


view.when(function() {
    map.addMany([locationpin]);
});
```

Expected O/P:

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some syntax errors in your code.

Try this:

```
view.on("click", function (evt) {  
  // Search for symbols on click's position
  view.hitTest(evt.screenPoint).then(function(response) {
    //loop over each graphics clicked
    response.results.forEach(function(result) {
      if (result.graphic.symbol.url=="images/Location-map.png"){
        result.graphic.symbol.url = "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/582/855/original/vector-location-pin-icon.jpg";
      } else {
        result.graphic.symbol.url = "images/Location-map.png";
      }
    });
  });
});
```